# OpenLayers: use upscaling to zoom a tile layer beyond the server's max zoom level by upscaling

Tags: openlayers, tile-map-service

I'm using OpenLayers 7 to display a tile layer from a tile service. The service only has tiles up to a maximum zoom level. At higher zooms, I would like OL to fetch maximum zoom level tiles and display them upscaled. How do I do this?

Setting `layer.setMaxZoom(SERVER_MAX_ZOOM)` causes the layer to disappear completely beyond SERVER_MAX_ZOOM, so that's no good.

I've also tried a tile loader function that blocks requests for higher zoom levels. This causes OL to display upscaled tiles provided they'd already been loaded (due to `useInterimTilesOnError`), but it won't fetch new tiles of level SERVER_MAX_ZOOM after panning.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/jrwtc2df/4/

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
const osm = new ol.source.OSM();
const getTile = osm.getTileUrlFunction();
// Cause a load error above zoom level 8.
// This simulates a server which returns 404 above this level.
osm.setTileUrlFunction((coord) => coord[0] <= 8 ? getTile(coord) : 'http://localhost/');
const map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      maxZoom: 10,
      source: osm,
    }),
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 51.5]),
    zoom: 8,
    maxZoom: 10,
  }),
});
```

The demo starts at level 8. Zoom in to level 9 or 10 and you see upsampled imagery (good). But after panning away, OL only attempts to load level 9/10 tiles which are unavailable, and shows nothing (bad).

I can overcome this by also setting `layer.setPreload(SERVER_MAX_ZOOM)`, but this fetches all zoom levels from 0 up to and including SERVER_MAX_ZOOM, which is quite wasteful.

I've thought of these other possible solutions:

- A tile loader function that, when zoom > SERVER_MAX_ZOOM, loads the SERVER_MAX_ZOOM tile, renders the relevant part of the tile into a canvas and sets as the output tile's src. This seems wasteful of resources.
- A tile loader function that, when zoom > SERVER_MAX_ZOOM, errors the request and tell the layer to add the correct SERVER_MAX_ZOOM tile to the tile queue, it should then be used as per setUseInterimTilesOnError(true). However I can't find a way to access the tile queue.
  I haven't implemented these yet, but might if there is no easier solution.

Comment: This is usually done by setting the `maxZoom` option on the source to SERVER_MAX_ZOOM

Comment: As @Mike wrote in his comment, you have to set `maxZoom` on layer source, not on layer. In your sample code that would be `const osm = new ol.source.OSM({maxZoom: 8});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Mike is the answer - my mistake was confusing the `maxZoom` option of a tile SOURCE with the `maxZoom` option of a tile LAYER.

The LAYER's `minZoom` and `maxZoom` control the range of zoom levels over which the layer is displayed, as described in my question. The SOURCE's `minZoom` and `maxZoom` tell OpenLayers the range of zoom levels it can supply tiles at.

So the solution is to set the `maxZoom` option of the SOURCE to `SERVER_MAX_ZOOM`, and the `maxZoom` option of the LAYER to a higher value. Then when the displayed zoom level is higher than `SERVER_MAX_ZOOM`, OpenLayers will fetch tiles from the source at its maximum zoom level as required, and display them upscaled.